# Applying Node Based Material to OBJ Loader (r79)

Tags: three.js

I try to apply Node Based Material to a obj model but it does not work :(
There is a limitation on the obj file with this Material type ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: In the ThreeJS examples (webgl_materials_nodes.html) i try to use (.Obj) model instead the "TeapotBufferGeometry": 

var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
        loader.load('obj/male02/male02.obj', function (object) {
            object.traverse(function (child) {
                if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                    mesh = child;
                }
            });
            scene.add(object);
        }, onProgress, onError);

I can see the model correctly but no material is applied over :(
if i use un simple SphereGeometry it s work.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works well with the obj file , I had not correctly applied my material :/